# Javascript Check all the custom checkbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I tried this script, to create a custom checkbox with the name parameter.

```
    function customCheckbox(checkboxName){
    var checkBox = $('input[name="'+ checkboxName +'"]');
    $(checkBox).each(function(){
        $(this).wrap( "<span class='custom-checkbox'></span>" );
        if($(this).is(':checked')){
            $(this).parent().addClass("selected");
        }
    });
    $(checkBox).click(function(){
        $(this).parent().toggleClass("selected");
    });
}
$(document).ready(function (){
    customCheckbox("name1");
    customCheckbox("name2");

})
```

display looks good on css. then I want to make a checkbox for checkall and uncheckall .. I tried this script ...

```
$("#checkAll").click(function(){
$('input:checkbox').not(this).prop('checked', this.checked);
});
```

only the default checkbox successful. Custom checkbox mine was not working.
please help fix.

simple html

```
    <label><input type='checkbox' id='checkAll' name='name1' class='selectall' /></label>

    <label><input type="checkbox" name="name2" value="1" /> 1</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="name2" value="2" /> 2</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="name2" value="3" /> 3</label>

    <label><input type="checkbox" name="" value="4" /> 4</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="" value="5" /> 5</label>
```

css :

```
    .custom-checkbox{
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 3px;
    background: url("https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/windows-8-metro-style/26/unchecked_checkbox.png") no-repeat;
}
.custom-checkbox:hover{
    background: url("https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/windows-8-metro-style/26/unchecked_checkbox.png") no-repeat;
}
.custom-checkbox.selected{
    background: url("https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/windows-8-metro-style/26/checked_checkbox.png") no-repeat;
}
.custom-checkbox input[type="checkbox"]{
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;            
    cursor: pointer;
    outline: none;
    opacity: 0;
    /* CSS hacks for older browsers */
    _noFocusLine: expression(this.hideFocus=true); 
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    -khtml-opacity: 0;
    -moz-opacity: 0;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/npywzvaj/2/)

Comment: `js` at Question appear to return expected results . Tried inspecting `input` elements at click event of `#checkAll` ?

Comment: updated the fiddle or try this http://jsfiddle.net/npywzvaj/9/

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#checkAll").change(function () {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $(".check").prop('checked', true);
    }else{
        $(".check").prop('checked', false);
    }

});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/npywzvaj/3/)

Try this one

[DEMO UPDATED](http://jsfiddle.net/npywzvaj/9/)

I added the class selected to span inorder to check the custom checkbox

Comment: This is not my intention.
I try to add my css and script >>>> [link](http://jsfiddle.net/npywzvaj/2/)

Comment: can you explain your intention?

Comment: i hope my custom checkbox... checked... try my demo !! please insert all script

Comment: there is something wrong, if I choose name2 first. then I choose to check all, the effect is reversed.

Comment: can you share a fiddle of the that?

Comment: your last fiddle, choose 1 2 3 first !!... then check all

Comment: what should happened?if it is checked already you cant uncheck it?it because it is checked already it will be unchecked because it toggles the class select

Answer (score 0):

I wrote some code for my own personal use that seems like it would fit this question nicely. Here is a link to the working jsfiddle I created... http://jsfiddle.net/www139/wpq6qjyf/

It would involve redoing the checkboxes but it might serve you better anyway. Here is a code demo...

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var checkboxes = document.getElementsByClassName('checkbox');
  for (var i = 0; i != checkboxes.length; i++) {
    if (checkboxes[i].hasAttribute('name') == false) {
      checkboxes[i].setAttribute('name', 'notChecked');
    } else {
      if (checkboxes[i].getAttribute('name') == 'checked') {
        checkboxes[i].setAttribute('name', 'checked');
        checkboxes[i].children[0].className = 'checkboxDotActive';
      }
    }

    checkboxes[i].onclick = function() {
      if (this.getAttribute('name') == 'checked') {
        this.setAttribute('name', 'notChecked');
        this.children[0].className = 'checkboxDot';
      } else {
        this.setAttribute('name', 'checked');
        this.children[0].className = 'checkboxDotActive';
      }
    };
  }
};
```

```css
/*
* PLEASE NOTE THAT THE 'checkboxDot' DIV MUST COME BEFORE ANY OTHER INNER MARKUP.
* IT MUST COME IMMEDIATELY AFTER THE PARENT DIV! IT WILL NOT WORK OTHERWISE!!!
*
* Thank you for showing interest in this code!
*/

/*IMPORTANT STYLES... THE STYLES LATER ARE NOT DIRECTLY RELATED THE THE CHECKBOXES*/

.checkbox {
  background-color: #eee;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 5px;
  display: table;
}
.checkbox input {
  outline: none;
  border: 0;
  background-color: transparent;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.checkbox .checkboxDot {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  -o-transition: all .5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .5s ease;
  -webkit-transition: all .5s ease;
  -ms-transition: all .5s ease;
  transition: all .5s ease;
}
.checkbox .checkboxDotActive {
  background-color: #01A1DB;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  -o-transition: all .5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .5s ease;
  -webkit-transition: all .5s ease;
  -ms-transition: all .5s ease;
  transition: all .5s ease;
}
/*END IMPORTANT STYLES*/

/*START IRRELEVANT STYLES*/

.valueButton {
  margin-top: 10px;
}
/*END IRRELEVANT STYLES*/
```

```html
<h1>Javascript, html, and css checkboes -- best browser support ever!</h1>


<h3>Normal checkbox</h3>

<div id="checkboxOne" class="checkbox">
  <div class="checkboxDot"></div>
  <input type="button" value="Item 1">
</div>
<div id="checkboxOneStatus"></div>
<input type="button" class="valueButton" onclick="document.getElementById('checkboxOneStatus').innerHTML = document.getElementById('checkboxOne').getAttribute('name');" value="Is it checked?">

<h3>Checked by default</h3> 
<div id="checkboxTwo" class="checkbox" name="checked">
  <div class="checkboxDot"></div>
  <input type="button" value="Item 2">
</div>
<div id="checkboxTwoStatus"></div>
<input type="button" class="valueButton" onclick="document.getElementById('checkboxTwoStatus').innerHTML = document.getElementById('checkboxTwo').getAttribute('name');" value="Is it checked?">
```

Remember that the HTML markup for the checkboxes must be in the exact order that it is in, otherwise the JavaScript will not work. This code algorithm will give you much more control over the styling of checkboxes and other elements. It doesn't require JQuery either. To make a checkbox checked by default, simply give the `.checkbox` div a `name="checked"` attribute and you are good to go. You may also have to override whatever current styles that you have in place for your CSS buttons since there is a button element included in each checkbox. Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that you have given your checkboxes the same name, therefore they are considered to be radio buttons by the browser (only 1 can be true).

Give them different names and you should be able to check them all.

Comment: has a different name anyway, and already repaired 
 
jsfiddle.net/npywzvaj/9  thank you